# Adding data from ResultSet to jTable

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, netbeans

I am working in NetBeans and am not too familiar with the java language in which I find answers to my question. No error is shown in my code but it fails to show data in the table.

```
try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname", "root", "password");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String query = "select gamename,score from player where score<>0 order by score desc;";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println("It reached here");
    while (rs.next()) {
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getObject(1), rs.getObject(2)});
        System.out.println("It reached here also");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

dtm is the `DefaultTableModel` for the table.

I have made it sure that there is no syntax error. But no data shows up in the table.

I wrote in class:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm;
```

In constructor I wrote:

```
dtm=(DefaultTableModel)tbl.getModel();
```

In table's properties, in model properties, I set the custom code as:

```
new DefaultTableModel()
```

I hope nothing goes in wrong there

Comment: How you set dtm to jtable ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I wrote in class:
    DefaultTableModel dtm;
In constructor I wrote:
    dtm=(DefaultTableModel)tbl.getModel();
In table's properties, in model properties, I set the custom code as:
new DefaultTableModel()

Comment: I don't understand your dtm data flow. Can you show complete minimal code ?

Answer (score 1):

The columns were not added to DefaultListModel.

```
    dtm.addColumn((Object)"Game Name");
    dtm.addColumn((Object)"Score");
```

That's why the data was not showing up